# Returning either render_template, or jsonify from Flask as jQuery response

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a login page, that after entering incorrect username or password displays an error in the paragraph [working], or redirects the user to the dashboard if the login was successful [not working].

The HTML for the login form looks as follows

```
<form id="login" action="/login" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login to the Metalworks</legend>
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<p id="result" style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold"></p>
```

then I have a JS script that sends a HTTP request to my webserver after hitting the submit button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").ajaxForm({
        url: "/login",
        dataType: "json",
        success: loginResult
    });
});

function loginResult(response)
{
    result = document.getElementById("result");
    if (!response.success)
    {
        result.style.color = "red";
        result.innerHTML = response.error;
    }
}
```

so far all of this works, I get the username and password in my Flask application, where I compare it to the accounts in the DB and if an error occurs, I return a jsonify-ed object with error, otherwise I'd like to make a redirection to the dashboard.html, which doesn't work

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("login.html", title="Metalworks Login");

@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST"])
def login():
    if "username" not in request.form or len(request.form["username"]) == 0: return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Username is not specified!"});
    if "password" not in request.form or len(request.form["password"]) == 0: return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Password is not specified!"});

    username = request.form["username"];
    password = request.form["password"];

    cursor = accountsCollection.find({"username":username});
    try:
        account = cursor[0];
    except:
        return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Could not find account {}!".format(username)});

    if account["password"] != password:
        return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Incorrect password!"});

    # this does nothing
    return render_template("dashboard.html", title="Metalworks Dashboard");
```

1, any ideas on how to properly redirect after successful login?

2, what is the proper way of handling the session, setting timeout etc?

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

You can use `redirect` to redirect user to other routes. 
For example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("login.html", title="Metalworks Login")

@app.route("/dashboard")
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", title="Metalworks Login")


@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST"])
def login():
    if "username" not in request.form or len(request.form["username"]) == 0: return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Username is not specified!"})
    if "password" not in request.form or len(request.form["password"]) == 0: return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Password is not specified!"})

    username = request.form["username"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    account = {"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}
    if account["username"] != username or account["password"] != password:
        return jsonify({"success":False, "error":"Incorrect password!"})

    return redirect("/dashboard")

app.run(debug=True)
```

`dashboard.html`:

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
```

Output after inserting `admin` as username and password:

[image: after login view]

**2.**

I would suggest to try [Flask-Login](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Login/) for login, logout and login_required functionalities.

From official documentation: [login-example using Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example)